# Can filling an employer abuse claim affect my chances of citizenship?

Tags: working-visas, canada, express-entry, pr

I arrived in Canada on a closed(employer-specific) work permit and was terminated. This happened amid the coronavirus pandemic. My employer quickly terminated me after bringing me here on a global skills strategy program, and my company has been reporting losses for quite some time. I was abused at work, I was told to do something and then terminated for doing that. It appeared fixed.

Now, I can wait for six months and wait for express entry to work out, thus having a break in my employment, or can apply under abuse of employer and try to get an open work permit. The latter is even suggested by a lawyer.

Would this look bad on my record when I apply for citizenship down the line?

Comment: What advice did your lawyer give you on that question?

Comment: He seemed to be okay with it, but might be just selling his services!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an opinion: I can’t see that will in any way interfere with a future citizenship application. First you’d have to become a permanent resident and live for five years in Canada. Take step one first before you concern your about step X.